# LWJGL shader normal's alias

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, vertex-shader

I'm writing my app with LWJGL and on some graphic cards (AMD Radeon series) I can not change the normal's name in vertex shader because something goes wrong and only one big triangle appears on the screen. Here is my code:

```
#version 150

//our attributes
in vec3 a_position;
in vec2 a_textureCoords;
in vec3 a_normal; //Here is an error

//send the color out to the fragment shader
out vec2 vTextureCoords;

void main(void)
{
    a_normal;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    vTextureCoords = a_textureCoords;
}
```

if I change shader to this:

```
#version 150

//our attributes
in vec3 a_position;
in vec2 a_textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

//send the color out to the fragment shader
out vec2 vTextureCoords;

void main(void)
{
    normal;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    vTextureCoords = a_textureCoords;
}
```

Everything works fine and mesh appear as it should be. Is it normal?
And my bind attribute function:

```
//Before
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(s_programID, 2, "a_normal");

//After
GL20.glBindAttribLocation(s_programID, 2, "normal");
```

## edit

Attributes locations in shader:

```
//Before
a_normal 0
a_position 1
a_textureCoords 2

//After
a_position 0
a_textureCoords 1
normal 2
```

Comment: which opengl version are you targetting at minimum?

Comment: My minimum is OpenGL 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to write something like this:

```
#version 150

#define POSITION  0
#define TEX_COORD 1 
#define NORMAL    2 

//our attributes
layout (location = POSITION) in vec3 a_position;
layout (location = TEX_COORD) in vec2 a_textureCoords;
layout (location = NORMAL) in vec3 a_normal;

//send the color out to the fragment shader
out vec2 vTextureCoords;

void main(void)
{
    a_normal;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    vTextureCoords = a_textureCoords;
}
```

And then on java you have something like:

```
interface Semantic {

   interface Attr {

      int POSITION = 0;
      int TEX_COORD = 1;
      int NORMAL = 2;
   }
}
```

that you will use in your `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribute` functions

Otherwise, remember to `glBindAttribLocation` *before* or `glGetAttribLocation` *after* linking the program

Ps: remember to do something useful with that `a_normal` otherwise the glsl compiler will optimize it out by removing it completely